# How to prevent duplicate code when implementing progressive enhancement?

Tags: php, javascript, code-duplication, progressive-enhancement

I'm running a PHP webapp that allows users to view lists of item.

The bare-boned site uses PHP to write the HTML to show the search results:

```
<body>
   <?php
      foreach($results as $item) {
         echo "<div class='item'>".
                 "<img src='images/items/".$item['imageName'].".png' />".
                 "<span class='itemDescription'>".$item['text']."</span>".
              "</div>";
      }
    ?>
 </body>
```

However, when Javascript is enabled, I use AJAX to display results:

```
function fireSearch(query) {
   $.post("ajax/search.php", {q: query}, function(items) {
      for (var i in items) {
         $("body").append(
             "<div class='item'>"+
                "<img src='images/items/"+items[i]['imageName']+".png' />"+
                "<span class='itemDescription'>"+items[i]['text']+"</span>"+
             "</div>";
      }
   }
}
```

I could simply write a PHP function called `get_item_html($item)` and make the AJAX request return the clean HTML and simply place it in the DOM, but if the request returns lots of results that would be a real waste of bandwidth when all I really need to construct the HTML is the `imageName` and the `text`.

Is this just something I have to cope with or is there some elegant solution?

And does this problem have a name so I can google it?

Comment: It's called templating. Some template formats can be used both server- and clientside.

Answer (score 1):

OK, got it.

The best solution I found is to use [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/), write some templates and read the templates in both Javascript and PHP.

The [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) library provides [PHP](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php) and [Javascript](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) implementation, so no worries there:

1. Create some `.mustache` templates
2. In PHP, use the classes and methods provided by [the library](http://mustache.github.com/) to create HTML and `echo` it
3. In Javascript, use the template by adding the `mustache.js` script, and for every template used by the page add a script tag with the contents of the template file `echo`ed in:
   `<script id="arbitraryID" type="text/mustache">`
   `<?php echo file_get_contents(__DIR__."/templates/myTmpl.mustache"); ?>`
   `</script>`
   The template is then available by doing (jQuery style):
   `var tmpl = $("#arbitraryID").html();`

Hope this helps anyone that finds this question open...

Answer (score 0):

I would let the ajax function return a json build, and then I would make your .append() into a custom minimized function to keep the size down, then you will have alot cleaner code as a result.

Comment: How does that solve the problem? I'll still have a PHP function and a Javascript function doing the same thing

Comment: Sadly I missread the thread and no, my answer wouldn't help at all. ~blames not having had coffee when reply was written~

Answer (score 0):

As Bergi mentioned, use a template to encapsulate the display of the information, and send only the imageName and text on the ajax requests.

There are many ways to implement templating (ive heard a lot of good things about handlebars.js, havent tryed it yet), a simple one would be to write the html markup with the data received on the ajax request and append it to the container, maybe using a simple function that you can later replace with a proper templating approach.

```
function drawItem(item) {
    return "<div class='item'>" +
             "<img src='images/items/"+item.imageName+"' />" +
             "<span class='itemDescription'>"+item.text+"</span>" +
           "</div>";
}

function fireSearch(query) {
    $.post("ajax/search.php", {q: query}, function(items) {
        for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
            $("body").append(drawItem(items[i]);
        }
    }, 'json');
}
```

ajax/search.php would return something like: [{"imageName":"blabla.png","text":"moomoo"},...]

Generated by a search.php file like this:

```
<?php 
echo json_encode(array(
    array("imageName"=>"blabla.png", "text"=>"moomoo"),
    array("imageName"=>"example2.png", "text"=>"second example")
));

?>
```

Comment: Thanks but I still can't understand from your answer how I won't need to copy code between PHP scripts and Javascript scripts

Comment: You dont copy code, in this case Javascript is used to send an AJAX request to the server that should return JSON encoded data. Use echo json_encode(yourarray) on the php script. Ill edit the post with a php snippet.

Comment: But for progressive enhancement I need PHP to know how to build the HTML. Knowing how to build a JSON string - compliant with the clientside script - isn't enough

Comment: I see. Only "elegant" solution i can see is Mustache (http://mustache.github.com/), but that's another library your adding to your app. If you really want to reduce bandwidth you could send the template of a search result item with the JSON results, this way only PHP needs to know how to draw a search item. I'm not sure the bandwidth improvement is worth the complexity, that would depend on the amount of visitors and resources you have.